# How do I print/read the HTML from a POST requests?

Tags: python, html, post, python-requests

Using this example : https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

[image]

This is part of the script I'm using :

```
url = "https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers[
        'User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'
    s.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'

    data = {"g-recaptcha-response": str(captcha["text"])}

    response = s.post(url, data=data)
```

Assuming that I'm able to solve the captcha, how could I print the HTML text of this page which is the result :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just access the html / body by accessing the response.text property.

See the docs right [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

If you need further parsing of the response you can use something like [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to parse the response.